# Node.js проблема с установкой плагина

Tags: node.js, socket.io

При освоении node.js по [данной статье](http://frontender.info/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs/#yaustanovilnodechtotepery) возникла проблема с установкой плагина socket.io. Перед этим успешно был установлен плагин express и все заработало отлично, но когда дело дошло до плагина socket.io - тут возникли проблемы. К вопросу прикрепляю [скрин окна терминала](http://youbiznes.ru/screen.jpg), в котором я пытался установить плагин socket.io. Установил .NET Framework, но не помогло. Подскажите, в чем дело...

Answer (score 1):

[[@Deathdrumer](/users/22437/deathdrumer)](/users/22437/deathdrumer), любой каприз за ваши деньги у преподавателей. Да и к тому же я бы на вашем месте для тестов и учебы просто воспользовался такой чудесной вещью как виртуализация(к примеру virtualbox) линукса. И мыши целы и волки сыты. А устанавливать порой приходится много всего.

---

Что касается ошибок, у вас там странный warning при npm install socket.io. Проверите, он там точно установился? И еще, в системе windows должны быть установлены:

1. Microsoft Visual C++
2. Windows SDK
3. Python 2.7

И может быть это дело заработает.

**Обновление**

Виртуальная машина служит только для того, что бы вы не переустанавливая свою систему смогли работать из под своего Windows в Linux. На счет переноса из Windows на Windows сервер не знаю, в Linux всего этого не надо.

Comment: хорошо, установлю я допустим все это на свой копьютер, допустим, все это у меня заработает, но как потом все это перенести на реальный сервер? На реальном сервере тоже придется ставить виртуальную машину, Microsoft Visual C++Windows SDK и Python 2.7???

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

там инструкция более корректная. и ссылки есть на установщики.

Comment: опять какой-то лабиринт: для того, чтобы установить первое, вам необходимо установить второе, а для того, чтобы установить второе, вам потребуется установка третьего, и т. д... Я уже столько всего установил на компьютер, что уже желание пропадает. Сколько это будет продолжаться? неужели, для того, чтобы воспользоваться технологией websocket, нужно проделать такой огромный путь? И что больше всего бесит - нужно переустановить ОСЬ и поставить linux. Да не хочу я этот линукс ставить!!!